# BeforeFeature hook get Feature name

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumberjs

I am implementing BeforeFeature hook and I want to know which feature I am in

```
    var hooks = function () {
        this.registerHandler('BeforeFeature', function (event, callback) {
        console.log(event.feature ????)
    });
};
```

When I debug, on the console, event.feature is undefined. I can do event.getName(), then obviously I get "BeforeFeature" as result. Anyone knows how I can get the feature that it's going to evaluate? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got the feature name:

```
event.getPayloadItem('feature').getName()
```

Same for scenarios, steps, etc.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/200